# Calculate distance between each latitude and longitude in rows

Tags: python, loops, distance

I have a file that contain station latitude and longitude with elevation as
shown below:

```
     sta        long        lat  elevation
0   ML39  104.498783  29.474033        420
1   ML03  104.476017  29.476300        492
2   ML01  104.474617  29.476233        471
3   ML02  104.475450  29.476400        489
4   ML04  104.476317  29.476517        499
..   ...         ...        ...        ...
71  ML76  104.523467  29.477933        360
72  ML77  104.524100  29.477917        375
73  ML78  104.524933  29.477633        397
74  ML79  104.526317  29.477483        375
75  ML80  104.527400  29.478117        369
```

I want to calculate the distance between each lat and long in two consecutive rows, I use these commands to do it for a single value but I am not sure how can I run a loop to extract lat and long from each row and get distance with respect to next line.

```
dist_m,_,_=gps2dist_azimuth(29.478383,104.481117,29.478483,104.481717,)
print (dist_m,_,_)
```

How can we run a loop to calculate the distance between each lat and long in rows?

Comment: What programming language?  What libraries or tools are you using?  Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: I am using python. Normally I used bash for all my work but this time I am try to learn Python

Comment: Break it into steps: 1) open the file, 2) iterate through it line by line, for each line (after the first) split it into components, extracting the two that you need, 3) read all of this into an appropriate data structure, 4) iterate over that data structure. If you don't know how to do any of the steps, read a tutorial. Alternatively, `pandas` can automate most of these steps, though using base python none of the steps require more than a few lines of code. If you get stuck, ask a focused question about the code that you have written.